# Api Keys and domains

Tags: facebook, api, key, api-key

Apologies in advance if this is already answered somewhere, but I didn't see it in searching.  How can I set up may Facebook app so the API key works for both http://mysite.com and http://www.mysite.com.  Right now www.mysite.com works fine, but mysite.com breaks when trying to use the API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the App Domain to both of them - you can now set multiple domains for the App Domain in the Dev app.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/570/

Comment: Not a problem. Glad I could help.